# Using SQLite for logging

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sqlite, rdbms

I want to use SQLite as database backend for WCF service logging. Everything looks good, but how can I extract database log file from real system and don't get database locked for inspecting/analyzing of logs? This system seems to be very load extensive and everytime I try to take database log file it takes away locked.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use SQLite's [Write-Ahead Logging](https://sqlite.org/wal.html) mode to enable a SQLite database to be read and written to concurrently.

There are advantages and disadvantages to using WAL instead of a rollback journal. Advantages include:

1. WAL is significantly faster in most scenarios.
2. WAL provides more
   concurrency as readers do not block writers and a writer does not
   block readers. Reading and writing can proceed concurrently.
3. Disk
   I/O operations tends to be more sequential using WAL.
4. WAL uses
   many fewer fsync() operations and is thus less vulnerable to
   problems on systems where the fsync() system call is broken.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite permits to have multiple processes/applications to have the same database file open for reading and writing (there is some locking involved when writing, but this is not typical to have big problems with it).

You should be able to have logging process to continuously log new rows into your database, and at the same time have offloading/extracting process copy older rows to some other location.

If you should not, however, copy database as a file using standard copy function while it is open, because it will most likely corrupt it (on Windows, it maybe even impossible due to strict locking).

Instead, have offloading process connect to database using standard SQLite API (or some scripting language with SQLite support), read rows using that API and create copy of that data elsewhere, for example in another SQLite database or in big "real" SQL database like MySQL, Postgres or MSSQL (or in text file if so inclined).

Comment: Tell me please can I connect ot SQLite and make its copy to another SQLite database?

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLite's [online backup](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) API to extract the data without having to lock the DB.